# Is it possible to set a field's value instead of replacing the reference with a new object when Deserializing with Gson?

Tags: java, serialization, gson, json-deserialization

I'm currently using GSON to for my serialization library, and I'm having a some difficulty with figuring out how to read a value from the JSON and use it to update a field's value, without changing the reference of the field. I'll give a reduced example of my issue:

```java
  public static class Property {
    String text;

    public Property(final String text) {
      this.text = text;
    }
  }

  public static class Delegate {
    final private Property property;

    public Delegate(final Property property) {
      this.property = property;
    }

    public String getValue() { return property.text; }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
      this.property.text = value;
    }
  }

  public static class ExampleWithPropertyAndDelegate {

    final Property textProp = new Property("Test");
    final Delegate delegate = new Delegate(textProp);
  }
```

So the way this works is that the `delegate` member of `ExampleWithPropertyAndDelegate` should always update the accompanied `property` member when `setValue` is called, e.g.

```java
    /* create the object we want to serialize/deserialize properly*/
    var example = new ExampleWithPropertyAndDelegate();
    /* setting the value via the delegate should update the underlying Property reference*/
    example.delegate.setValue("Value Changed");
```

This example works exactly as expected when using the constructor. However, when deserializing, this no longer works. The underlying `Property` that the delegate references is no longer the same instance as the `example.property` member, that is `example.property != example.delegate.property`, even though it should.

I know this is happening since Gson uses the `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` to actually set the object for the field, after construction. But is there a way to stop this from happening, say for any `Property` fields, instead of replacing them with a new instance via reflection, instead having it just set the value of the existing instance?

Comment: I guess you could redesign it: 1) are all fields (properties and their respective delegates) supposed to be serialized to JSON?; 2) what if Gson would not be responsible for that? say, delegate fields are annotated with i.e. `@Delegate.For("propertyName")` so that other reflection-driven code would restore object delegates once the object is deserialized?; 3) if not, then you have to store association keys (`@For` value, surrogate keys, etc) in JSON and make these associations work together in your type adapter `read` method (possibly with `@Expose(deserialize = false)` for delegates).

Comment: Realistically, I only need 1 of either the property field OR the delegate field to be serialized, so long as the delegate still references correct property after deserialization. I've tried using an `ExclusionStrategy` to skip one or the other, but the two fields are still out of sync after deserialization.

I think then the best course for me at the moment would probably be a custom serializer/deserializer for the classes that contain the delegate and property. It's a bit more fragile, since I'll need to do this for any serialized class which uses this Delegate/Property pattern.

Comment: You could then even not use reflection/Gson. If you'd have DTO and domain objects, it's easy to map them forwards and backwards (e.g. automated with tools like MapStruct). So if you'd have a DTO to domain objects mapper, then it could be the place where such delegates could be restored at, in a "post processing" phase. I don't think Gson should be responsible for that.